# Text Resize as the user types

Tags: jquery, resize

So I've searched a ton of sites, and what I am looking for is, as the user types, the text automatically resizezs smaller (or larger, if they delete something).

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not understanding. Let's say I type "12" then hit the backspace key, then type "345". What should happen as I hit each of those 5 keys? Would 1 get smaller when I typed 2, but larger when I hit backspace? When I type 3, will 1 shrink again? Howe about 4 and 5? Just how small or large will text get? Will all of the text change size on each keystroke, or just some number of most-recent characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try some simple algorithm like this:

```
$(function() {
    var $in = $("#in"),                                     // <== could be a div
        w = $in.width();
    $in.css("font-size", 20*30/$in.text().length);
    $in.click(function() {
        this.contentEditable='true';
    });
    $(document).keyup(function() {

        $in.css("font-size", 20*30/$in.text().length);       // <== Resizing algo

    });
});​
```

### **[Try it out with this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N32pd/)**

Comment: This works exactly the way I need it to, but it is not contained in my DIV. Is there any special CSS I would have to use? You can see my demo here: http://twmorton.com/magicpreviewjquery/

Comment: The problem is that when you hit the first letter the letter is gigantic. I would make an upper limit using Math.min(). I'd also change the CSS a little, but it looks like it's basically working. Take a look at this ==> http://jsfiddle.net/bwTVR/ ----------- Vertical align is tricky. Read this ==> http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html --------- You might also have to play around with the resizing algorithm.

Comment: @Tom - Looks like it works. I see the font size change. So what you have to do is adjust the initial font size and rate of font size change so that it fits into the box. Just use a smaller initial font.

Answer (score 0):

Just put an event on .keydown() which will check the length of .text() inside the element and resize it accordingly